# Hive UNION ALL returning incorrect results

Tags: hadoop, hive, hiveql, union-all

I have five tables that I need to union them.
My problem is that the first table has 6362 rows and with the union all I should have 14580 (sum of all five tables) but i still having 6362 with union all.

I try this:

```
CREATE TABLE example
AS
SELECT * FROM(
SELECT
A,
B,
C,
D
FROM nvl2
UNION ALL
SELECT
A,
B,
C,
D
FROM nvl3
UNION ALL
SELECT
A,
B,
C,
D
FROM nvl4
UNION ALL
SELECT
A,
B,
C,
D
FROM nvl5) TMP;
```

Also I have tried without the subquery, but the result is the same.

Thank you!

Comment: You used nvl5,nvl4,nvl3,nvl2 in your SQL so your `UNION ALL` should return sum of count of these tables. How many rows these tables - nvl5,nvl4,nvl3,nvl2 have ?

Comment: They are 14, 1108, 5669 and 6362 rows respectively.